# How can I convert a string to integer in common lisp?

Tags: common-lisp

How can I convert a string to integer in common lisp?
For example, if I input a string "-64", I want to get an integer number -64.
thx.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Fortunately, the standard provides a method: [PARSE-INTEGER](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_parse_.htm).

```
CL-USER> (parse-integer "-64")
-64
3
```

Comment: I am not an experience lisper (especially with common lisp), but IIRC Paul Graham's book has a decent function reference in it.

Comment: `parse-integer` returns two values, first is base10 integer read from string and the position in the string of the first unread character.

Answer (score 6):

This page may help:

http://hyperpolyglot.org/lisp